# Angular jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith with queryParams not working

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this test:

```
it('should redurect to admin programs', () => {
    ...

    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/admin/programs', {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}}]);
});
```

And its throwing this error:

```
Error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with 
[ [ '/admin/programs', Object({ queryParams: Object({ pub_status: 'active' }) }) ] ] but actual calls were 
[ [ '/admin/programs' ], Object({ queryParams: [ pub_status: 'active' ] }) ].
```

Also the activated route mock is like this:

```
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    snapshot: {
      queryParams: {
        'countryValId[]': 'ES'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And navigate spy is like this:

```
router = TestBed.get(Router);
navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
```

How do I solve it? This annotation is very strange:

```
{ queryParams: [ pub_status: 'active' ] } <-- wtf this is not a proper array
```

[image: error in terminal]

Thanks!!

Comment: can you add `navigateSpy` code please

Comment: it's added now!

Comment: I think you should be checking the `queryParams` separately

Comment: you suggest I can't use toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Comment: yes, you can try `toHaveBeenCalledWith(queryParams)`

Comment: mm no, if I call only with queryParams it says the same error

Comment: the problem is that the call that is executed includes everything, the path and the params

Comment: From first sight - you have extra brackets in expect, try toHaveBeenCalledWith('/admin/programs', {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}})

Comment: if I remove the 'extra brackets' it says: Error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ '/admin/programs', Object({ queryParams: Object({ pub_status: 'active' }) }) ] but actual calls were [ [ '/admin/programs' ], Object({ queryParams: [ pub_status: 'active' ] }) ].

Comment: @ismaestro can you post a screenshot of the error you are getting. I think you can test the `queryParams` to subscribing to the `activatedRoute` and use `activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(data=>expect(data['pub_status']).toBe(true)`

Comment: @Aravind I added the image with the error!

Comment: @ismaestro
Also, I'm wondering if your spy is `calledThrough()` and check my edited above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem,

1. Pass flatten parameter in toHaveBeenCalledWith method.

   ```
   expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      ['/admin/programs'], 
      {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}}
   );
   ```
2. separate out the mostRecent call arguments and verify them one by one. Use `toEqual` method for object comparision.

   ```
    const [routeLink, queryParamsObj] = navigateSpy.calls.mostRecent().args;
    expect(routeLink).toEqual(['/admin/programs']);
    expect(queryParamsObj).toEqual({queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this is the syntax of Router navigate method, you have an error in array brackets **[]**

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/programs'], {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}});
```

and not

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/programs', {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}}]);
```

so it has to be

```
expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/admin/programs'] //here is the error
    , {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}});
```

Comment: It says: 
Error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ '/admin/programs' ], Object({ queryParams: Object({ pub_status: 'active' }) }) ] but actual calls were [ [ '/admin/programs' ], Object({ queryParams: [ pub_status: 'active' ] }) ]. Seriously I don't understand why it says  [ pub_status: 'active' ] ...

Comment: My navigate is this.router.navigate(['/admin/programs'], {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}})

Comment: And my expect is     expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/admin/programs'], {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}});

Comment: can you show the code when you call this.router.navigate ??

Comment: yeah, it's like this: this.router.navigate(['/admin/programs'], {queryParams: {pub_status: 'active'}})